# CS50 - blur, image is correctly blurred but fails check 50

Tags: c, cs50, blur

After a lot of work I've got the problem solved but the check50 test does not pass. (Some integers are not rounded in the way they want)

[image: outputs]

Any ideas what to do with rounding up / down?
(I've used the `round` function - doesn't seem to work)

The answer is always off by 1 - so it seem to be a rounding problem.

```c
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //creathing a copy of image in a global scope.
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j < width; j++ )
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////
     for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j < width; j++ )
        {
            // creating veriablles
            float avgRed,avgGreen,avgBlue;
            avgRed = 0;
            avgGreen =0;
            avgBlue=0;

        //creating all the special cases (corners, top, bottum,left side, right side)
        //top-left corner VV
        if (i==0 && j==0)
        {
            int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue;

            avgRed = round(totalR/4);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/4);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/4);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;
        }
        // top-right cornder VV
        else if  (i==0 && j == width-1 )
        {
             int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;

            avgRed = round(totalR/4);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/4);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/4);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;
        }
        //top row
        else if (i == 0  && j!=0 && j!=width-1 )
        {
            int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;


            avgRed = round(totalR/6);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/6);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/6);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;

        }
        //bottom left corner
        else if (i == height -1 && j == 0 )
        {
            int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j+1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j+1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j+1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue;

            avgRed = round(totalR/4);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/4);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/4);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;
        }
        //bottom right corner
        else if ( i == height -1 && j==width-1 )
        {
            int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j-1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j-1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j-1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;

            avgRed = round(totalR/4);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/4);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/4);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;

        }
        //left side
        else if (j == 0 && (i!= 0 || i!= height-1) )
        {
            int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j+1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j+1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j+1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;

            avgRed = round(totalR/6);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/6);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/6);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;


        }
        // right side
        else if (j == width-1  && i!= 0 &&  i!= height-1)
        {
             int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j-1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j-1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j-1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;
            avgRed = round(totalR/6);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/6);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/6);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;


        }
        //bottom
        else if (i== height -1 && j!= 0 && j!= width-1)
        {
            int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen+ copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;

            avgRed = round(totalR/6);
            avgGreen = round(totalG/6);
            avgBlue = round(totalB/6);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            
image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;

        }
        //everything else
        else if ( i!=0 && i!= height-1 && j != 0 && j != width-1)
        {
            int totalR,totalG,totalB;
            totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed+copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed +copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed +copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed ;
            totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen+copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen+copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen+copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
            totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue+copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue+copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue+copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;

            avgRed = (totalR/9);
            avgGreen = (totalG/9);
            avgBlue = (totalB/9);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(avgRed);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =avgGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =avgBlue;
        }

        }

    }
}
```

I tried using `float`s and rounding the numbers using the `round` function. Seems to be off by 1 every time it fails.

Comment: `avgRed = round(totalR/6);` In this assignment, `round` is useless because you already lost the remainder of this integer division. You must force the compiler to use floating point division: `avgRed = round(totalR/6.0);`

Comment: "I tried using floats" You only used `float` to store the result. But the calculation itself is important. If you only have an integer value, storing in a `float` will not bring back what you lost before.

Comment: @Gerhardh it works now! i understand the problem. thanks for the help.
in conclusion, doing the round function was correct but without forcing the compiler to make it into  float number i would lose the remainder...

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the avarage, one should use 6.0 instead of just 6 in order to force the compiler into counting it as float number and not integer thus not "losing" the remainder.
after that the rounding function will work proparly and the Check50 Test will PASS.

thanks to @gerhardh for helping.

example for fixed code:

```
     else if ( i!=0 && i!= height-1 && j != 0 && j != width-1)
    {
        int totalR,totalG,totalB;
        totalR = copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j-1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed+copy[i-1][j].rgbtRed +copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed +copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed ;
        totalG = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j-1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtGreen + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j].rgbtGreen+ copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen+copy[i-1][j].rgbtGreen+copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen+copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
        totalB = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j-1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j+1 ].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue+copy[i-1][j].rgbtBlue+copy[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue+copy[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;

        avgRed = roundf(totalR/9.0);
        avgGreen = roundf(totalG/9.0);
        avgBlue = roundf(totalB/9.0);
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = (avgRed);
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen =(avgGreen);
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue =(avgBlue);
    }
```